# jquery select each element who's previous element matches selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following question and I ve been struggling with it for quite a while. Im sure the solution is very simple but still I cant see it.
In the following set of rows I want to select only the ones which contain class .replace or .empty or .delete or .insert and are preceded by rows which contain class .equal:

```
<tr>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="equal"> sth</td>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="equal"> sth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="equal"></td>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="equal"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>want to be 1st selected row</th>
    <td class="replace"></td>
    <th></th>
    <td class="replace"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>dont want this one but it selects it</th>
    <td class="replace"></td>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="replace"> sth</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="equal"></td>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="equal"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>want to be 2nd selected row</th>
    <td class="delete"></td>
    <th></th>
    <td class="delete"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="replace"></td>
    <th>sth</th>
    <td class="replace"> sth</td>
</tr>
```

So Ive come up with this as a jQuery( "prev + next" ) selector but it doesnt seem to work as it selects only the first row I want and then all others that have .replace in them and only after that jumps to the next .replace which was preceded by .equal :

```
$('tr:has(.equal) + tr:has(.replace),tr:has(.empty),tr:has(.delete),tr:has(.insert)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the previous elements, then use `.next`.

```
$(".equal").closest("tr").next().has(".replace,.empty,.delete,.insert");
```

It only selects table rows that have the specified classes and are preceded by a row that containing the `equal` class.

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly more efficient, but wordier:

```
$("tr:has(.equal)").next("tr:has(.empty), tr:has(.insert), tr:has(.delete), tr:has(.replace)")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4M5X/), [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/complicated-selectors-vs-more-selectors)

Comment: yep thats the one I came up with after Kevin B's answer. But overall his answer I accepted.

Comment: Yes, just a trade-off between readability and speed. since the speed difference is small in this case (until you reach 10k rows)

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely nastier to read. A few milliseconds is probably not worth it.